How to resolve an "Already in Cache" error when using INSERT .... SELECT
I'm connecting to Ignite via JDBC 10800, and trying to INSERT a row into a table, that has three columns.
 - THE_KEY
 - MY_OTHER_ID
 - SOME_DATA

If I try to insert a second record with the same value for THE_KEY, I get a regular SQL error telling me I'm trying to insert a duplicate. So far so good.
But, when I start with an empty table, and do this:
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (THE_KEY, MY_OTHER_ID, SOME_DATA)
SELECT ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from MY_TABLE WHERE MY_OTHER_ID = ?)

I get an error that says:
OperationError: 50000: Failed to INSERT some keys because they are already in cache [keys=[123]]

Some additional facts:

Even though I get the message, it DOES insert the row
This does not happen when I connect to Ignite running on my local machine, only when I connect to one that is running on the cloud

Any clues to what might be going on here?

You don't say which version of Ignite, but I tried it with 2.16 and 2.15, and it works as expected in both.
If you run the SQL command twice you get the same error you note in your question.
So I'm not seeing a bug in Ignite, which suggests it's in your client code or your environment. You might need to share more information about your client or your infrastructure.
